# Python: Queue between a Process and a Process of a Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Im starting three Processes (a2,a3,a4) from a Process(a1). These three (sub)Processes need to send data to another process(b1). I cant make this Process(b1) in the (sub)Processes of a2,a3,a4 (this is one function being called three times) because it will spawn three Processes instead of just one. For this reason, the handling of the Queue seems to get difficult. All the functions are looping indefintely. How would i solve this? A simple form of the code is here:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def Process_B(): #q4: multiprocessing.Queue
    while True:
        if q4.qsize() > 0:
            var1, var2, var3 = q4.get()
            print(var1, var2, var3)
            #here is where i cant get the data

def Process_A2_3_4(q123: multiprocessing.Queue):
    supProcesses = SubProcesses123()
    while True:
        if q123.qsize() > 0:
            var1, var2, var3 = q123.get()
            supProcesses.doSomething(var1, var2, var3)
            

class SubProcesses123:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def doSomething(self, var1, var2, var3):
        print('doing something')
        #this needs to put something in a Queue
        #same Queue for all three Processes(a2,a3,a4)
        #Data will be received by Function: Process_B

class Process_A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a2 = Queue()
        self.a3 = Queue()
        self.a4 = Queue()
        self.startProcess234()
        self.doSomething()

    def startProcess234(self):
        a2 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.a2, "a2"))
        a3 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.a3, "a3"))
        a4 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.a4, "a4"))
        a2.start()
        a3.start()
        a4.start()
    
    def doSomething(self):
        print('doing something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieve = Process(target=Process_A)
    retrieve.start()
```

So a single Queue need to be made which will be used by Processes(a2,a3,a4) to send data to Process_B. The question is how? When i make a Queue in main or in Process_A and feed it to Process_A2_3_4, it does put something in the Queue(at least no errors) but im unable to retrieve the data from the queue in the other process. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use the same queue for a2, a3, and a4, then why are you creating and passing three different queues?  Just create one and pass it to all.

Comment: @TimRoberts no those needs to be 3 different Queues. I want one Queue to feed data from SubProcesses (which are 3 processes) to the Process_B

Comment: They can all share the same queue, like the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing you want to do.  Create one queue to feed the input dudes (the "A" processes), and one queue for those dudes to feed their output to the consolidator dude (the "B" process).

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time

def Process_B(q4):
    while True:
        var1, var2, var3 = q4.get()
        print("in B", var1, var2, var3)

def Process_A2_3_4(q123, q4, name):
    print(name,"starting")
    supProcesses = SubProcesses123(q4, name)
    while True:
        var1, var2, var3 = q123.get()
        supProcesses.doSomething(var1, var2, var3)

class SubProcesses123:
    def __init__(self, q, name):
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    
    def doSomething(self, var1, var2, var3):
        print('in SP123', var1, var2, var3)
        self.q.put( (var1,var2,var3) )


class Process_A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q1 = Queue()
        self.q2 = Queue()
        self.startProcess234()
        for _ in range(20):
            self.q1.put( (1,2,3) )
            time.sleep(1)


    def startProcess234(self):
        a2 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.q1, self.q2, "a2"))
        a3 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.q1, self.q2, "a3"))
        a4 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.q1, self.q2, "a4"))
        b = Process(target=Process_B, args=(self.q2,))
        a2.start()
        a3.start()
        a4.start()
        b.start()
    
    def doSomething(self):
        print('doing something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieve = Process(target=Process_A)
    retrieve.start()
```