# Python: shared variable across three Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to have a shared value between 3 different processes. The code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def Process_B(q4: multiprocessing.Queue):
    while True:
        if q4.qsize() > 0:
            var1, var2 = q4.get()
            print(var1, var2)

def Process_A2_3_4(q123: multiprocessing.Queue, q4: multiprocessing.Queue, name):
    supProcesses = SubProcesses123(q4, name)
    while True:
        if q123.qsize() > 0:
            var1, var2, var3 = q123.get()
            supProcesses.doSomething(var1, var2, var3)
            

class SubProcesses123:
    def __init__(self, q4: multiprocessing.Queue, name):
        self.name = name
        self.q4 = q4
        self.sharedlist = []#this list needs to be shared between the three processes.
    
    def doSomething(self, var1, var2, var3):
        print('doing something')
        self.q4.put(var1,var2)

class Process_A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a2 = Queue()
        self.a3 = Queue()
        self.a4 = Queue()
        self.b1 = Queue()
        self.startProcess234()
        self.doSomething()

    def startProcess234(self):
        a2 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.a2, self.b1, "a2"))
        a3 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.a3, self.b1, "a3"))
        a4 = Process(target=Process_A2_3_4, args=(self.a4, self.b1, "a4"))
        b1 = Process(target=Process_B, args=(self.b1,))
        a2.start()
        a3.start()
        a4.start()
        b1.start()
    
    def doSomething(self):
        print('doing something')
        #self.a2.pu(var1, var2, var3)
        #self.a3.pu(var1, var2, var3)
        #self.a4.pu(var1, var2, var3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieve = Process(target=Process_A)
    retrieve.start()
```

I tried to condense the code a bit without leaving out anything important. Every way i can think of leads to the problem that the three processes are completely seperate. Mind, they do need to be seperate, i just need to find a way to be able to have 1 shared list. It is unfortunately not an option to use the Queue from Process_B to handle the task, it really needs to be some form of shared list between the three processes (Process_A2_3_4). Im also unable to just make a Queue for the three processes because as far to my knowledge you can use the queue from 1 process to another but not from one process to multiple.

Im scratching the back of my head. If anyone has a solution or an idea, it would be very much appreciated if you could share it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: A manager may help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers

Comment: Did we already answer this question?  Why is a queue not the right answer?  I showed you how to have three processes read from one queue and write to one queue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298269/python-queue-between-a-process-and-a-process-of-a-process

Comment: I need those three Queues to be three queues(handling different data and its fed to the Process_A2_3_4 from Process_A ). This is a question regarding using 1 shared value from within the Processes(SubProcesses123). So created within one of the SubProcesses123 and used by all the SubProcesses123, and then updated on a decisecond bases from any of the three processes@TimRoberts

Comment: I'm going to go with the previous answers. If you need a shared (modifiable) list, then you are almost certainly doing it wrong, and are going to destroy whatever benefits you need from multithreading.   What are you trying to achieve with your shared list?  You're not really showing us.

Comment: each Process is recieving data from a source on high frequency. I need the three processes. Calculations are done in each process for the data from each source. The format of the data is made the same. When a certain condition is met, a variable needs to be updated for each process(basically blocking a part of the code, changing a condition). I cant handle the change in condition anywhere else because it changes the structure of the calculation. Please let me know if its still too unclear, if so, i will re-create the question with more detail.@FrankYellin

Comment: If you just to be able to pass around a boolean, then multiprocessing.Event may be what you want.  For more complicated stuff, multprocessing.Value or .Array